# How can multiple results be returned for salt minions

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to know both a pillar value and the result of a command for all my minions. Is there anyway to combine the result in one call?

I'm looking for something that would work like this

```
$ salt '*' cmd.run 'systemctl status <process>' pillar.get 'name'
```

Is something like that possible with the salt command? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092979/how-can-i-aggregate-saltstack-command-results/40046905#40046905) mentions the survey.hash runner, that allows aggregating the results by output, but that is the closest I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

`$ salt '*' cmd.run 'systemctl status <process>; salt-call pillar.get "name"'`

Salt-call runs locally on the minion, therefore returning only the pillars belonging to that Minion.